# update node' child element position in D3 force layout

Tags: javascript, d3.js, visualization, force-layout

I am new to d3. and early today i have tried some d3 force layout example, it works pretty well.

But when I DIY it and make every node a `g` element, and append child `circle` and `text` to it, the position of these children not updated automatically.

here is the [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RRUzZ/292/)

By the way, in this example, I call node.append('someElement') 3 times

-first time: 
`node.append('g')` > it becomes `<g></g>`

-second time: `node.append('circle')` > it becomes `<g><circle></circle></g>`

-last time : `node.append('text')` > it becomes `<g><circle></circle><text></text></g>`

as i thought, last time should also include `text` into `circle`, but not , why? Thanks

Comment: [This example](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1153292) should help.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I solved this.

Use transform is the right way to update the position of the children whose parent bound to the data.

so append the `text` and `circle` to the `g` node is the right way.

here is the [jsfiddle update](http://jsfiddle.net/RRUzZ/294/)

answer for my second question is,

the 2nd and 3rd append is append to the `g` because before there is one line code that

```
    node = node.enter()
        .append("g")
        .attr("class", "node");
```